# Override Wordpress admin function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to override `get_sample_permalink_html` from wp-admin/post.php. If I modify the file directly, my change works. However I would like to do this in a cleaner way, which means within a plugin, so that it's future-proof. Here's what I've tried, in my PHP plugin file:

```
add_filter('get_sample_permalink_html', 'custom_get_sample_permalink_html', 1, 3);
function custom_get_sample_permalink_html( $id, $new_title = null, $new_slug = null ) {
    (...)
}
```

It breaks the page without displaying an error, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the function has a filter that you can use, not to "override" the function, but to manipulate its output:

```
$return = apply_filters('get_sample_permalink_html', $return, $id, $new_title, $new_slug);
```

So, you need the following:

```
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink_html', 'custom_get_sample_permalink_html', 15, 4 );

function custom_get_sample_permalink_html( $return, $id, $new_title, $new_slug )
{
    // Manipulate the $return as you wish, using your own stuff and the passed variables:
    // $id, $new_title, $new_slug

    return $return;
}
```

`15` is the priority and means: "do it in the last possible position", you can increase it if necessary.
`4` is the number of arguments the function is receiving, checked in the original `apply_filters` call.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I hadn't understood this filter mechanism. Basically what I've done is configure the filter to do the same things as the default function, except for the shortening part that I wanted to get rid of. Might not be 100% optimized but it's in wp-admin so who cares ;)